# How to match and subset strings from one column and a corresponding adjacent column

Tags: r

I am trying to plot an upset plot using string matches in one column that correspond with names in another column.

I've managed to do this in a clunky long format:

```
'1000Genome' <- Biomart[str_detect(Biomart$Variant.supporting.evidence,"1000Genomes"),]$Variant.name 

'freq' <- Biomart[str_detect(Biomart$Variant.supporting.evidence,"Frequency"),]$Variant.name

'TOPMed' <-  Biomart[str_detect(Biomart$Variant.supporting.evidence,"TOPMed"),]$Variant.name

'gnomAD' <- Biomart[str_detect(Biomart$Variant.supporting.evidence, "gnomAD"),]$Variant.name

'Cited' <- Biomart[str_detect(Biomart$Variant.supporting.evidence, "Cited"),]$Variant.name

'ESP' <- Biomart[str_detect(Biomart$Variant.supporting.evidence, "ESP"),]$Variant.name

'ExAC' <- Biomart[str_detect(Biomart$Variant.supporting.evidence, "ExAC"),]$Variant.name

'Phenotype_or_Disease' <- Biomart[str_detect(Biomart$Variant.supporting.evidence, "Phenotype_or_Disease"),]$Variant.name

df = list('1000Genome' = sample(`1000Genome`),
         'TopMed' = sample(TOPMed), 'freqeuncy' = sample(freq), 'gnomAD' = sample(gnomAD), 'Cited' = sample(Cited)
         ,'ESP' = sample(ESP), 'ExAC' = sample(ExAC), 'Phenotype_or_Disease' = sample(Phenotype_or_Disease))

table <- as.data.table(df)
upset(fromList(table), order.by = "freq")
```

I tried cutting this down using loops:

```
    Evidence <- c("1000Genomes", "Frequency", "TOPMed", "gnomAD", "Cited", "ESP", "ExAC", "Phenotype_or_Disease")

for (i in Evidence){
     upset_data <- data.frame(Biomart[str_detect(Biomart$Variant.supporting.evidence, i), ]$Variant.name)
}
```

and this works, however, it doesn't subset each match like the first method. Does anyone have any advice?

Example data:

```
name <- c("rs123", "rs124", "rs125", "rs126", "rs127", "rs128", "rs129", "rs130")
Source <- c("dbSNP", "dbSNP", "dbSNP", "dbSNP", "dbSNP", "dbSNP", "dbSNP", "dbSNP")
chromosome <- c("17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17")
evidence <- c("TOPMed", "Frequency", "Cited", "Frequncy, Cited", "Disease", "ESP", "TOPMed", "GWAS") 

Biomart <- data.frame(name, source, chromosome, evidence)
```

I want to match the evidence to specific strings and get the corresponding rs name with it.

Comment: You are overwriting `upset_data` every iteration of the loop. If you provide a reproducible example I am sure someone can help you

Comment: If I try putting upset_data <- for (I in evidence) it creates a null output in values